# DataGridView Refresh - How to not re-write the whole grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

After adding a row to a DataGrid, I would like to update my DataGridView (with the input source of said DataGrid) using that new row. However when I use `.Update()` and `.Refresh()`, the whole of the grid gets re-drawn. When refreshing relatively quickly (around 4 times per second), this creates an unpleasing jolty effect. I would like to find a way to add my row to the DataGridView, without re-drawing the whole thing, therefore removing the DataGridView.

C# Winforms

Comment: *After adding a row to a DataGrid, I would like to update my DataGridView*: do you mean you have an old DataGrid Control and a DataGridView? Bound to the same data source? Or something else? -- Post some code to clarify your scenario. `Update()` and `Refresh()` (the latter is `Invalidate()` + `Update()`) are related to the graphic that renders a Control's UI, not its data. So, usually, you don't need to call any of these when adding / removing data. The source of data needs to send data change notifications, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a data binding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

This means the DataGrid is bound to e.g. a DataTable.